# perl: split array into matches and non-matches

Tags: arrays, perl

I know you can use `grep` to filter an array based on a boolean condition.  However, I want to get 2 arrays back: 1 for elements that match the condition and 1 for elements that fail.  For example, instead of this, which requires iterating over the list twice:

```
my @arr = (1,2,3,4,5);
my @evens = grep { $_%2==0 } @arr;
my @odds = grep { $_%2!=0 } @arr;
```

I'd like something like this:

```
my @arr = (1,2,3,4,5);
my ($evens, $odds) = magic { $_%2==0 } @arr;
```

Where `magic` returns 2 arrayrefs or something.  Does such an operator exist, or do I need to write it myself?

Answer (score 7):

It's probably most succinct to simply [`push`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) each value to the correct array in a `for` loop

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @arr = 1 .. 5;

my ( $odds, $evens );

push @{ $_ % 2 ? $odds : $evens }, $_ for @arr;


print "@$_\n" for $odds, $evens;
```

#### output

```
1 3 5
2 4
```

Answer (score 6):

[`List::UtilsBy::extract_by`](http://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy#extract_by) is like [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) but it modifies the input list:

```
use List::UtilsBy 'extract_by';
my @arr = (1,2,3,4,5);

my @evens = @arr;
my @odds = extract_by { $_ % 2 } @evens;

print "@evens\n@odds\n";
```

Output:

```
2 4
1 3 5
```

There is also `List::UtilsBy::partition_by`:

```
my %parts = partition_by { $_ % 2 } @arr;
@evens = @{$parts{0}};   # (2,4)
@odds = @{$parts{1}};    # (1,3,5)
```